# How to get the last value from the list using python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
data = ['reply': '{"osc":{"version":"1.0"}}']
data1 = ['reply':'{"device":{"network":{"ipv4_dante":{"auto":"1.0"}}}}']
```

I need to get only the "1.0" value from data and data1 using python 3.6.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I need to get "1.0" from the above data.. how can i do this

Comment: the data & data1 is invalid datatype in python you should send either in a dictionary or whole thing in string.

Answer (score 0):

Your data and data1 are invalid datatypes in python so I converted them into the valid dictionary.

```
from operator import getitem
data = {'reply': {"osc":{"version":"1.0"}}}
data1 = {'reply':{"device":{"network":{"ipv4_dante":{"auto":"1.0"}}}}}
def get_item(keys, dict_):
    return reduce(getitem, keys, dict_)
print(get_item(['reply','osc','version'], data))
print(get_item(['reply','device','network', 'ipv4_dante',"auto"],data1))
>>>1.0
   1.0
```

Another Approach that data and data1 as string:

```
class GetValue:

      def __init__(self, string):
            self.string = string
            self.new_keys  = {}


     def clean_data(self, data):
        if data[2] == '{':
            get_json_data = len(data) - 3
        else:
            get_json_data = len(data) - 1
        modified_data = [val for val in list(data[data.find(':')+1:get_json_data])
                        if val is not "'" ]
        return json.loads(''.join(modified_data))

      def get_recurvise_key(self, data, dict_):
            for key, val in dict_.items():
                self.new_keys.setdefault(data,[]).append(key)
                if isinstance(val, dict):
                    self.get_recurvise_key(data, val)
            return self.new_keys.get(data)

      def get_value(self):
            get_data = self.clean_data(self.string)
            get_keys = self.get_recurvise_key(self.string,get_data)
            value = reduce(getitem, get_keys, get_data)
            return value

data = """['{"device":{"network":{"ipv4_dante":{"auto":"1.0"}}}}']"""
data1 = """['reply':'{"device":{"network":{"ipv4_dante":{"auto":"1.0"}}}}']"""

obj_data = GetValue(data)

obj_data1 = GetValue(data1)

print(obj_data.get_value(), obj_data1.get_value())
>>> 1.0 1.0
```

Comment: I will get the result ['{"osc":{"version":"1.0"}}'] from my script and from this ['{"osc":{"version":"1.0"}}'] i should get "1.0" value and sometimes the data will be ['{"device":{"network":{"ipv4_dante":{"auto":"1.0"}}}}'] . In any condition i need to get "1.0" value if data is varying also.

Answer (score 0):

You can get that result recursively like:

#### Code:

```
def bottom_value(in_data):
    def recurse_to_bottom(a_dict):
        if isinstance(a_dict, dict):
            a_key = list(a_dict)[0]
            return recurse_to_bottom(a_dict[a_key])
        return a_dict

    return recurse_to_bottom(json.loads(in_data['reply']))
```

#### Test Code:

```
import json

data = {'reply': '{"osc":{"version":"1.0"}}'}
data1 = {'reply':'{"device":{"network":{"ipv4_dante":{"auto":"1.0"}}}}'}

print(bottom_value(data))
print(bottom_value(data1))
```

#### Result:

```
1.0
1.0
```

Comment: I will get the result ['{"osc":{"version":"1.0"}}'] from my script and from this ['{"osc":{"version":"1.0"}}'] i should get "1.0" value and sometimes the data will be  ['{"device":{"network":{"ipv4_dante":{"auto":"1.0"}}}}'] . In any condition i need to get "1.0" value if data is varying also.

Comment: @raghavendrat, I made a small change you might want to try again.

Answer (score 0):

After fixing the data:

```
data1 = {'reply':{"device":{"network":{"ipv4_dante":{"auto":"1.0"}}}}}
```

keep taking the value from the dictionary as long as it remains a dictionary:

```
d = data1
while isinstance(d, dict): 
    d = list(d.values())[0]
print(d)
#1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try regex :

```
import re
pattern=r'(?<=")[0-9.]+'

data1="""['reply': '{"osc":{"version":"1.0"}}']"""
data2="""['reply':'{"device":{"network":{"ipv4_dante":{"auto":"1.0"}}}}']"""

def find_value(data):
    return re.findall(pattern,data)[0]
```

output:

```
print(find_value(data1))
```

output:

```
1.0
```

second:

```
print(find_value(data2))
```

output

```
1.0
```